# how to embed spring to vaadin

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, vaadin

I have big project on vaadin. As you know there is init() method which is start point in vaadin application. Now i have to realise RestService on my database server inside my vaadin app. But i don't know how my ResrService to join with my vaadin application. Both app work correctly.
in RestService there are requestmapping annotations.
(for example https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
which reserve specific url for yours needs( i don't know how to devide this explicity when i embed my restservice with reserving these urls). And there is problem in start point of app how to specify this.

i want to do so (
for example

example.com/vaadin/.....   this is vaadin app

example.com/rest/....  this is place for requesting to restService

```
    @RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

sorry for my bad english!!!

Comment: You probably need something like Vaadin CDI (https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-cdi.html) with Spring integration for Vaadin or CUBA Platform (https://github.com/cuba-platform/cuba) with integrated Spring, Vaadin and REST-API

Comment: You could make 2 different WAR-packages, one with "rest" and one with "vaadin" context path deployed. But I guess it should be possible to have both in one web app but idk how.